# Video Encoding over multiple computer?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video

Is it possible, to render a single video file, with more than one pc?

Comment: Yes, i seen a guy that use the network with others computers, to use all the GPU in same time for render. i dont know how he did...

Comment: One simple way to render a sequence of frames on multiple machines is to simply create different .blends with the start and end -frames selected in a brainy way. Eg. out of 200 frames, the first machine renders frames 0-50, the second machine grinds frames 51-100, the third works it's way through frames 101-150 and the last finishes it up with 151-200. Then you take all the rendered frames and combine them in the sequencer. Also, if you want to distribute a single frame accross many machines, have a look at the netrender addon. (AFAIK it is included in the default blender releases)

Comment: It was done in Renegad Software, they made a virtual machine with 18GPUs with custom software. But that was for rendering, not encoding a video file. Blender can't even encode on multiple cores, and you would like to encode on multiple PC's..I am very skeptical about this.

Comment: @user277143 netrender doesn't work correctly in new releases and encoding must be done on single system to get 1 video.

Comment: @Jerryno I apologise for spreading misinformation about netrender. My bad. It was the first thing to come to my mind.

Comment: I don't think encoding over multiple computers would be a good idea. Render to image sequences in each one and encode as video in a single machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answers... I asked this question, because I need to render 4K video files with 30fps. So a single video of 10min, needs a huge time output as video file...

Comment: @rudolf97 then you better use some other app for this job: Nuke, AfterFX, etc. Fusion is for free.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44906/2843) to "How to make VSE render faster?" will help you accomplish this. You can split this process up on several computers as wished and join all the frames into your final video via ffmpeg later.